# Use MSBuild to concatenate JavaScript files with regexes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild, concatenation

I concatenate javascript in msbuild like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <JsFiles Include="wwwroot/**/*.js" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <JsLines Include="$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(%(JsFiles.Identity)))"/>
</ItemGroup>
<WriteLinesToFile Lines="@(JsLines)" File="wwwroot/bundle.js" Overwrite="true" />
```

That works, but when the source files contain regexes:

```js
let foo = bar.replace(/\[\d+\]/, '[10]');
```

Then they are written like so:

```js
let foo = bar.replace(//[/d+/]/, '[10]');
```

In fact this line:

```js
// \/
```

Is written like this:

```js
// //
```

And this:

```js
\\
```

Is written like this:

```js
//
```

Notice how it mangles those inputs into comments. The concatenated file is thus invalid.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I added [Feature Request: Types for file paths and plain text](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/9624) for MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines are creating an item collection.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <JsLines Include="$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(%(JsFiles.Identity)))"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

But the `Include` tries to interpret the value provided as a set of file paths delimited by semi-colons. The escape characters in the regular expressions are treated as directory separators.

Don't use `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText()` in an Item `Include`.

Instead, use the [`ReadLinesFromFile` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/readlinesfromfile-task?view=vs-2022).

e.g.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <JsFiles Include="wwwroot/**/*.js" />
</ItemGroup>
<ReadLinesFromFile File="%(JsFiles.Identity)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="JsLines" />
</ReadLinesFromFile>
<WriteLinesToFile Lines="@(JsLines)" File="wwwroot/bundle.js" Overwrite="true" />
```

The `ReadLinesFromFile` task doesn't interpret the lines that are read from the file. The task will be batched for each unique `%(JsFiles.Identity)`. Each batch will add to the `JsLines` Item collection.

**Update:** The code that is shown works correctly on Windows. But there is a bug (or bugs) on macOS and Linux.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the concatenated file exhibits the same problem. For example, if one of the input files contains `/\d+/` then the output file will have `//d+/`. If one of the input files contains contains `new RegExp('\\d+')` then the ouput file will have `new RegExp('//d+')`, I think the issue is a fundamental incompatibility of msbuild on linux/macos as seen by this long-standing [bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3468).

Comment: The cited bug is a different issue but definitely related. I reproduced the bug with the `ReadLinesFromFile` task on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked down the issue to long-standing compatibility bugs between msbuild and linux / macos - see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3468) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/1622).

These are insidious bugs which are hard to detect, as one doesn't expect this behaviour.

#### Please upvote those github issues so they know we want them to be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

*Please upvote the bug issues mentioned in my other answer, so we can use msbuild without hacks.*

But until then, here is a workaround:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <JsFiles>Pages/**/*.js wwwroot/js/**/*.js</JsFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
<Exec Command="bash -c 'shopt -s globstar; cat $(JsFiles) 2>/dev/null >| wwwroot/dist/bundle.js; true'" StandardOutputImportance="high" />
```

It does everything in bash. Notes:

- Explicitly specify the command to run in bash (`bash -c '...'`); on my setup for example, it'll otherwise run in dash (which lacks globstar support)
- Use spaces in the file listing, not semicolons as done for the msbuild approach
- Enable the globstar option (`shopt -s globstar`) so one can use `**` in the file listing
- Redirecting errors to /dev/null is needed when one or more paths do not contain scripts; the `true` is needed to prevent such errors from failing the msbuild task